# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse - change breakpoint for a specific navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to change breakpoint for collapse for a specific navbar, not all navbars.

I want this navbar to collapse at 500px:

```
  <ul class="navbar-collapse-500 nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Link1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link3</a>
    </li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
```

I want to add CSS style for my class .navbar-collapse-500 which will add collapsing for 500px and do not touch collapse breakpoint for standard navbar-nav class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add this to your CSS file:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-text {
        float: none;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
        display: block!important;
    }
    .collapsing {
        overflow: hidden!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: it will change styles for all navbars which use classes .navbar-header, .navbar-toggle. I don't want to touch common classes and also I don't want to duplicate all standard bootstrap CSS code for my navbar which is an easy copy-paste solution. I wonder if I can add only a small piece of CSS code (for example, a new class .navbar-header-500).